# How can I power IP camera from same lan cable as wifi AP over POE?

Tags: security

I want to mount IP camera on my house , problem is that I do not want to drill into isolation or have cables hanging around house. There is already one lan cable mounted and connected to wifi ap which is powerd by POE injector.

Now how can I use this one cable to power two devices. I would buy wifi IP camera so data cables of lan cable will stay into wifi AP.

What device would allow me this?

Comment: There are adapters that can couple voltage and video signal. I used to use them all the time but now with high resilouton cameras we use they cause some lines in the screen.

Comment: You need an "Ethernet Switch" to divide your existing ethernet cable. Power for POE should be injected after the switch.

Comment: @Tyson -- I wonder if there are switches that can power themselves from PoE and also supply (a smaller amount of) PoE to downstream ports?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's reasonable to have a switch that injects POE (Google search "Ethernet switch with PoE" however I would avoid "switch with passthrough" as there is no way power can be equitably divided and still have enough current to be meaningful.  For future upgrade unlike to keep components like that simple and not combined.

Comment: @Tyson I don't suppose respectable vendors would make PoE passthrough switches if they didn't work. You just need to read the docs on your particular switch and make sure you don't try to draw too much juice through it. For example [this](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28370/~/poe-pass-through-switches) and [this](http://www.cablinginstall.com/blogs/2011/06/cisco-s-poe-passthrough-switch-powers-itself.html)

Comment: @craig and Hawking Technology is considered a respectable vendor of networking technology by some, it's considered "cheap" by others, and I would never buy their junk product (again) personally.

Comment: @Tyson Great. The links I provided point to Netgear (not my personal favorite, but generally just fine) and Cisco, not Hawking Technology. Having said that, I'm not disparaging Hawking Technology because I am simply not familiar with their equipment. You didn't even mention whether they manufacture PoE passthrough switches, so I'm not sure how it's helpful to bring them up?

Answer (score 2):

There are PoE pass through switches.

The issue is that you have multiple devices, IP camera, WAP and the switch is likely to exceed your power budget.

Also the cost of any switches, splitters or injectors that may be able to do this would likely exceed the cost of a short cable run.

Wifi cameras generally suck and your issue is power anyway, IP data is not very power intensive.

If though the cable run for some reason is nigh on impossible, ideally see if there are altenative power sources near your WAP, if so you may be able to install a small PoE switch at that location or possibly a power supply for a camera or the WAP also which removes the need for PoE pass through and a normal switch or small PoE powered switch can be used. Not the finest solution but gives you a bit more options.

Comment: I am using an [IPCamPower 2 Port Extender](http://ipcampower.com/ipcp-ext2p) for something like this. It's $50 on Amazon.

You need a true PoE switch upstream of this, preferably 802.11at compatible so there's enough power to run everything. Any PoE converters / dongles have to be connected to the *output* of the extender.

Answer (score 0):

The PoE splitters I'm aware of have Ethernet and DC power outputs. Regardless, you can't run two Ethernet devices off of one Ethernet cable unless you use a switch, or one of the devices has a switch built into it. Some Wireless AP's have two Ethernet ports, for example, which means they contain a 2-port Ethernet switch. Most (or at least many) of those devices, though, have a PoE input and a non-PoE passthrough.

You're probably going to need to either install a PoE passthrough Ethernet switch somewhere near your AP and run separate Ethernet cables to the AP and the camera, or just pull another Ethernet home run back to the switch you're feeding the AP from. You can put the PoE injector anywhere along the length of that cable. It doesn't have to be anywhere near the endpoint device.

Answer (score 0):

Netgear GS105PE ~$80 PoE pass through switch.  (there are others like it, but it's a good example)

Plug the cable currently going into your access point into the switch, then one cable from the switch to the AP, another to the camera.

Depending on which type of PoE you have upstream and the usage of the now 3 devices, you may or may not have enough power.